# Passing Javascript variable to PHP variable using AJAX on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to convert my javascript variable to php variable. I can get the value of "1" when i click the link but i want to echo it using PHP or i want to store it on a PHP variable.

this is my Javascript and PHP code on the same page.

```
<?php $userid = 1; ?>

<a href="#" onclick="sendEmail(<?php echo $userid; ?>)" > Send Mail </a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendEmail(userid){
    var sendID = userid;
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.php", 
                    data: { toID: sendID },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function( toID ){
                        alert( toID ); }
                });
        });
}

<?php

$userid = $_POST["toID"];
echo $userid;

?></script>
```

no display when i echo it.

thanks.

Comment: Maybe some should point out that js is run on the client and php on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, because your **ajax request** go to another request, and your current php file can't get it.

```
yourFile.php -> Ajax Request -> yourFile.php
|                               |
|                               |-- here your $_POST['todID'] has the value, but it's other thread
|-- here your $_POST['toID'] is empty
```

**UPDATE 1:** You can use **success** callback to show results or do any.

```
success: function( data ) {
  alert( data ); //<--- this have the result of your ajax request
  javaScriptVar = data;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** If you need send email in the same file that shows the form, you need put at head:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['toID'])) {
 sendmail($_POST['toID'], "subject", "body");
}
?>
```

Comment: what if i will put this code on sendEmail.php

<?php

$userid = $_POST["toID"];
echo $userid;

?>

Comment: You can't call php functions within html code, so, '<a href="#" onclick="sendEmail(<?php echo $userid; ?>)" > Send Mail </a>' won't work, you need... i will update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you are passing a userid to ajax request and getting another userID, Do one thing to achieve that:

```
<input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>">
<a href="#" onclick="sendEmail()" > Send Mail </a>
```

and in you js code:

```
function sendEmail(){
var sendID = $('#userid');
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php", 
                data: { toID: sendID },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function( toID ){
                        //alert( toID ); 
                        // update the userID
                        sendID(toID);
                    }
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: what will happen on my PHP code where will i echo it? on the ajax.php? if yes, can i put the mail function on ajax.php?

Comment: @user3109628 where is your ajax.php file? For what you are using `$userid`?

Comment: cause you use url: "ajax.php" so im wondering what's that for.. im using $userid to query a user..

Comment: why if i alert var sendID it displays [object Object]?